# Store very long text: BLOB or TEXT

Tags: database, sqlite, text, blob

I have several texts which are very long (tens of thousands of characters). Which is the best option to store such texts in SQLite: as TEXT or as BLOB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite's [database file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), TEXT and BLOB values are stored in *exactly* the same way.
The only difference is that the bytes of a TEXT value are assumed to be valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer: **TEXT**

**BLOB** is good only for binary files and generally storing any binary data (images, songs, etc) in a database is not a good idea and is to be done only as a last resort.

Here is list of data types in SQLite and which data type from SQL are their corresponding ones:

> - **INTEGER** – INT, INTEGER, TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT,    UNSIGNED BIG INT, INT2, INT8
> - **TEXT** – CHARACTER(20), VARCHAR(255), VARYING CHARACTER(255),NCHAR(55),    NATIVE CHARACTER(70), VARCHAR(100), TEXT,
>     CLOB
> - **BLOB** (no datatype specified) – NONE
> - **REAL** – REAL, DOUBLE, DOUBLE PRECISION, FLOAT
> - **NUMERIC** – NUMERIC, DECIMAL(10,5), BOOLEAN, DATE, DATETIME

For a really good guide about SQLite refer to this [guide](http://team.158ltd.com/2014/02/28/sqlite-how-to-create-a-proper-data-model-with-sqlite/).