# Sqlite Storing String Value as TEXT or NUMERIC or BLOB

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

Currently im having an issue where i need to store a big amount of characters in a SQLite Table, the question is what it's the most effective way to storage a very very long text, get the value and save it as BLOB or even NUMERIC, i add an example of what im talking about (example, no real code)

```
String veryLongText ="This text is ganna have a zillion lines of boring text, that can be increasing 1,000 lines per week.";

db.saveThisText(getByteArrayFromString(veryLongText);

public byte[]getByteArrayFromString(String value){
    return value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

or save the whole text like a... well text.

This question it's pretty close to be the same as this: [Store very long text: BLOB or TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547904/store-very-long-text-blob-or-text)

But what can be the best option?

Comment: The question you linked to already contains the answer to your question. Use TEXT.

Comment: There is no [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) called "NUMERIC". How is this question different from the linked one?